# Downloading an exe file but when it runs it gets 16-bit error

Tags: c#, exe, 16-bit

Hello I have a program which it will have an auto updater. I made an updater that will downloads a newer version of the program and runs it after it has downloaded   but when it runs it has an error "Unsupported 16-bit Application".
The Program works but it doesn't when I download it with a program.

Here is the code for the updater

```
File.Delete("PopCorn.exe");

            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/PopCorn.exe?w=AAD2iYqKqKT5zNWl_xRCLoNAzMGcNwMttKQtONthLLOuTw&dl=1&_subject_uid=492001599"), "PopCorn.exe");
            web.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(web_DownloadProgressChanged);
            web.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
            label5.Text = ("Downloading Latest Update");



   async void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        label5.Text = "Updating Done";
        await Task.Delay(200);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PopCorn.exe");
        Application.Exit();

    }




    void web_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int bytesin = int.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        int totalbytes = int.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        int kb1 = bytesin / 1024;
        int kb2 = totalbytes / 1024;

        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = kb1.ToString() + "KB out of " + kb2.ToString() + "KB (" + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%)";
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

    }
```

Comment: are you in a 64bit windows? win64 doesn't support win16 apps anymore. there's no way you could EVER run that win16 app without using a virtual machine or other "heroic" measures.

Comment: I've also seen the 16-bit error occur when your .exe is horribly corrupted, it's akin to the "Not a valid win32 application" error and might be related to your download method not completing. Is the local copy of the .exe the exact same filesize in bytes on the server?

Comment: Not related, but you may want to reorder your code slightly so it only deletes the old version after the new version has been successfully downloaded, so that if it fails for whatever reason you can still offer to run the old version.

Comment: Im Running 64 bit Windows, I will try so it reordering the code

Comment: I Fixed it I did what James Thorpe said I reordered the code and put a await Task.Delay(60); Just before it deletes and instead of using PopCorn.exe I used popcorn.exe